# Issues with @segment/consent-manager and Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to use the [@segment/consent-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@segment/consent-manager) for a Next.js 13 project, but running into problems. I've tried to using [this Next.js example in the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@segment/consent-manager#example-in-nextjs) in my code, but nothing seems to work and I keep getting this error:

`Server Error TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.`

The standalone script works if I put it in the Head and use `Script` elements like this:

```
import Script from "next/script";
import * as snippet from "@segment/snippet";

export default function Head() {
  const loadSegment = () => {
    const options = {
      apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SEGMENT_WRITE_KEY,
      page: true,
      load: true,
    };
    return snippet.min(options);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <title></title>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <Script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: loadSegment() }}
        id="segmentScript"
      />
      <Script
        id="consentManagerScript"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `window.consentManagerConfig = function(exports) {
            var React = exports.React
            var inEU = exports.inEU

            var bannerContent = React.createElement(
              'span',
              null,
              'We use cookies (and other similar technologies) to collect data to improve your experience on our site. By using our website, you՚re agreeing to the collection of data as described in our',
              ' ',
              React.createElement(
                'a',
                { href: '/docs/legal/website-data-collection-policy/', target: '_blank' },
                'Website Data Collection Policy'
              ),
              '.'
            )
            var bannerSubContent = 'You can change your preferences at any time.'
            var preferencesDialogTitle = 'Website Data Collection Preferences'
            var preferencesDialogContent =
              'We use data collected by cookies and JavaScript libraries to improve your browsing experience, analyze site traffic, deliver personalized advertisements, and increase the overall performance of our site.'
            var cancelDialogTitle = 'Are you sure you want to cancel?'
            var cancelDialogContent =
              'Your preferences have not been saved. By continuing to use our website, you՚re agreeing to our Website Data Collection Policy.'

            return {
              container: '#target-container',
              writeKey: '${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SEGMENT_WRITE_KEY}',
              shouldRequireConsent: inEU,
              bannerContent: bannerContent,
              bannerSubContent: bannerSubContent,
              preferencesDialogTitle: preferencesDialogTitle,
              preferencesDialogContent: preferencesDialogContent,
              cancelDialogTitle: cancelDialogTitle,
              cancelDialogContent: cancelDialogContent
            }
          }`,
        }}
      />
      <Script src="https://unpkg.com/@segment/consent-manager@5.3.0/standalone/consent-manager.js" />
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm able to proceed with my project using the standalone script, but I feel there might be an issue with using the `ConsentManager` component in Next 13. Has anyone else had any issues with this? Or does anyone have any solutions that I haven't seen? I'd prefer to use the `ConsentManager` component if I can.

Version = "next": "13.1.1",

Comment: Hi, you should [avoid using image in your questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: That's why I also added alt-text, but thank you.

Comment: Hi @Holden I am running into the same issue trying to get Segment Consent Manager working with Next 13.  Did you ever get any further with this?  Or did you just stick with the standalone script?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that @ segment/consent-manager assumes that analytics is available on the window object, but you don't have access to the window object on none client components. [Usage with @segment/analytics-next](https://github.com/segmentio/consent-manager/issues/193#issuecomment-979382827)

Adding

```
'use client'
```

should solve this problem.